# Error in loading AngularJs with RouteProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I am new to angularJs, while using routeProvider angularJs through following error. I tried everything but I did not found an solution.

**Errors:**

```
Error: Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string from viewApp
TypeError: angular.$$minErr is not a function
```

Here is my html file

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="angular.min.js" language="javascript" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
<title>Anguler App</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="viewApp">
<a href="#/click">Home</a>
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

AngularJs code that I am using.

```
var myapp=angular.module('viewApp',[]);
myapp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when("/click",{
            templateUrl:"partialview.html"
            }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've linked the angular-route.js but not using it in your app. Do a dependency injection -

```
var myapp=angular.module('viewApp',['ngRoute']);
```